# VSCode with pyenv-virtualenv, trigger automatically?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyenv-virtualenv

Recently I've been using pyenv-virtualenv for my python projects and with the vscode extension "Python Environment Manager", and I love the combo.

However I currently need to activate the virtualenvs manually through the plugin.

Does anyone know if there's a good way and have tested it to do it automatically?

Can I for for example create some kind of file structure that would allow vscode to automatically select the right pyenv-virtualenv when I open a file in a specific repo/folder?

Answer (score 3):

I've found that if I configure the `Python: Venv Path` setting to the location of my pyenv folder it will automatically pick the correct virtual environment. Although I always open VS Code from a terminal using `code .`.

[image]

Comment: In conjunction with your answer that solves the issue. If you have multiple folders containing virtual envs (using pyenv and wirtualenv-wrapper for example) you can add them in the `Venv Folders` section of VSCode with the same effect!

Answer (score -1):

- Open a folder as a workspace
- Use the command to create a new virtual environment in the terminal,

  [image]

  *The above command will generate a `.venv` folder in the current workspace, which is a virtual environment named `.venv`*
- Select the `.venv` virtual environment interpreter in the **Select Interpreter** panel

  [image]
- New terminals will automatically activate the environment

  [image]

***When you open this folder with vscode next time, VScode will select the last interpreter by default. If you have not changed it, then you will select the `.venv` virtual environment by default when you open this folder in the future.***

Comment: That is an alternative to using pyenv-virtualenv -- does not answer the question.